# How do I enable WideLinks on samba's recent release?

Tags: samba, vfs

Note: I am aware of the security issues and reasons why it's been changed. I still require the use of wide links.

Samba's recent versions have made it where WideLinks are now supposed to be loaded as a per-share vfs module, but I can't figure out how to install the vfs module in order to use it. I have it set in the vfs modules, but the vfs module doesn't actually exist. I am using mx linux (the new march release) which comes with samba 4.13.13-Debian. I installed samba_vfs_modules but that didn't contain the widelinks one.

Answer (score 1):

You still enable it using the same `wide links` option. Samba will [automatically](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=commitdiff;h=886d2c09b84787062c98e26dfccceaba6420cf6c) load the VFS module when needed. (The [Debian bullseye](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/arm64/samba-vfs-modules/filelist) package contains the module; if MX Linux is missing it, that's deliberate on MX Linux's side and you should probably ask them why that's the case.)

You also need to disable the SMBv1 Unix extensions mode (as well as the upcoming SMBv3 POSIX extension), as it exposes symlinks client-side and conflicts with server-side following of the links.

```
[global]
    wide links = yes
    unix extensions = no
```

(Disabling POSIX extensions also mostly mitigates the security issue in question, as clients can no longer arbitrarily create symlinks with POSIX-mode on and then trick the server into following them with POSIX-mode off; they can only follow what was already created server-side.)

Comment: I needed to add "allow insecure wide links = yes"